# Location of /etc/fstab in El Capitan

Tags: ntfs

I want to activate the [NTFS support](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x-mavericks--cms-21434).
But I can't find the /etc/fstab on my mac.
osx 10.11.5 El Capitan

Comment: you mean you can't find /etc/ or you can't find fstab inside it? fstab may not exist at all; you can simply create it, it's a text file

Comment: I can't find the file fstab. But will it work, if it does not exist anymore?

Comment: It only exists if something needed one before, otherwise you need to create it yourself

Comment: You're right. That's all. If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/etc/fstab` doesn't exist by default, only if anything has previously needed it. `fstab` itself is merely a text file. If nothing has previously needed one, you can make it yourself.

The standard header appears to be a comment with vague instructions as to how the syntax works...

```
# fstab
#
# Identifier  mount point  fs type  options1
#
```

below that is your mount or ignore instruction, e.g.

```
UUID=C126C736-1585-3D12-9CF1-F95EFF0CF744 none hfs rw,noauto
```

or

```
LABEL=[drivename] none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

There is far more information on `fstab` at https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/fstab.5.html than I could possibly précis here, or type `man fstab` in Terminal.

Comment: The manual page for `fstab` is included in OS X, in a Terminal type `man fstab`, or directly from Apple [FSTAB(5)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/fstab.5.html). There is no need to link to a Linux OS Wiki which contains some information that is not at all applicable to OS X.

Comment: @user3439894 Unfortunately Apple has apparently decided to scrub all its command line documentation from its site. So that link no longer works.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, Which is exactly why it says "or type `man fstab` in Terminal."

Comment: @user3439894 Sure, and that’s great. But having a working link would also be good. Unfortunately Apple absolutely hates documentation.

Comment: All the dev links moved after WWDC2020. They're stil there, you'll just have to find them again. When you find it, you could always link it back from here for future users.