# macOS equivalent of Linux's /etc/fstab configuration file

Tags: macos, filesystem

In Linux, there's a configuration file `/etc/fstab` that lists the file systems (typically hard disk partitions) that are to be mounted at boot time.

macOS and Linux share the same UNIX linage. A file with the same name is not available in macOS, as apparent from the output shown below:

```
$ less /etc/fstab
/etc/fstab: No such file or directory
```

What is the equivalent configuration file in macOS?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/244575/279727) answer @WangGaowei.