# How to prevent macOS from popping up "disk not readable" for my external drive without making any change to the disk?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, dialog

Similar question: [How to get rid of "The disk you inserted was not readable" and auto ignore it? (without installing apps)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332860/how-to-get-rid-of-the-disk-you-inserted-was-not-readable-and-auto-ignore-it). However, in their case they were able to create an additional readable volume to prevent this from showing up. In my case, I cannot create such a volume since my disk is full, and my volumes are not adjustable. Also, I am open to open-source app solutions if they exist.

**Note:** Differently from the other questions asking how to fix the drive, my intention is to silence this notification/warning, and **keep my drive as is** (disk is already full and volumes cannot be adjusted).

This is for an old macBook Air running macOS 11.7. However, if you have an answer for macOS 13 please post too.

I have an external hard drive that contains partitions/volumes that are **intentionally** not readable by macOS directly. I hope that when I plug in this drive to my macBook, macOS shall not pop up the dialogue saying "The disk you attached was not readable by this computer", so I do not have to click to ignore it every time.

I expect fixes done on macOS, not on my drive because my drive does not need a fix.

[image: Disk not readable dialogue]

Comment: @Allan It is the same request, but their situation can be worked around by creating a dummy readable volume on the external drive, while mine cannot. My volumes cannot be resized.

Comment: @Allan It is a similar question indeed, so it would be up to you to keep the "duplicate" mark. However, I tend to allow installing apps, but not allowing adjusting the disk.

Comment: There’s about 5 similar questions to yours with no answers except the one tagged.  See these [search results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=Disk%20not%20readable%20&searchOn=3). The answer is likely it can’t be disabled but there is a workaround.

Comment: @Allan I see. Again, if you feel this question should be marked as duplicate please go ahead. However, I do believe my request is pretty specific. I checked your search, most of them are in these categories, except the one you mentioned earlier: (1) This pops up but they do not know why because they plugged in something that is not a drive. (2) This pops up for some drive that they want to be able to read, but likely their drive has some problem that needs a fix.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/443414/disable-the-disk-you-attached-was-not-readable-by-this-computer-for-disk @Allan This one is very similar though it does not have an answer. Interesting I did not see it before. Likely due to the other categories have too many questions that contain the same keywords.

Comment: They are all asking how to disable which is what ties all together.  However, this is actually voted on because we can all be mistaken .

Comment: I'd see if setting it as noauto in FSTAB might work. I'm no expert in this, but I use to to prevent mounts - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/244575/85275